How to pass array of Files to Server Action?
NEXTJS
I am trying to to submit a form to server action with array of Files.
const onSubmit = async (data: PostData) => {
    const result = await createPostAction(data);

When I try to submit I am getting an error:

Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Server Actions. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.

This error disappears if do not include an array of Files (images) in my form:

Is there any way to bypass this or submit files to server actions in other way?

JS File objects exist only in the client-side browser, so you can't just magically POST it, consider that your DTO is being serialized somehow, but note that you can't JSON-encode a File (and no-one should be using Base64 to transfer large binaries) - the correct way to do this is by either using MIME multipart requests, or using a separate PUT/POST request with a binary request body for each file.
